# Slick slider not changing active slide position

Tags: php, css, slick.js

I'm working on a slick slider that contains 3 figures with a background image. The first slide works as it should but the following slides all fail to show up. The inspector shows that each of the slides following the first one maintain their inactive slide position given by slick which pushes them offscreen. It does work when I simply use `<img />` instead of `<figure>` or `<div>`. I'd use `<img />` if it wasn't for the sizing issues these gave me.

I loop the content so I can easily control the amount of slides

```
<div class="hero__background">
  <?php foreach ($images as $image) { ?>
     <div class="hero__background-image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image['url']; ?>');"></div>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

And this is the current CSS

```
&.hero {
  position: relative;
  height: 550px;

  .hero__background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: lightgray;
    z-index: -999;

    hero__background-image {
      background-size: cover;
    }

    .slick-list,
    .slick-track,
    .slick-slide {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

And the JS as requested :)

```
$('.hero__background').slick({
  infinite: true,
  autoplay: true,
  fade: true,
  speed: 600,
  arrows: false,
  dots: false
});
```

What could be the cause for background images to fail? Any help and advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can I see the js you've got to initialize the slider? could be related to the slides to show and slides to scroll options of the slick plugin.

Comment: Sure! I added it to the question :)

Comment: Thanks for adding this. I would try to add to the js options slidesToShow and slidesToScroll. Have a look at the documentation too: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick

And if this doesn't solve it would need to see your page and inspect it to troubleshoot

Comment: I set both slidesToShow and slidesToScroll to 1. Didn't change anything sadly. It's currently in early stages of development so I don't have an online page to share. But the first block of code is basically all there is to it. It's nothing fancy just a simple slider that fades images periodically.